# toLocaleString return unexcepted characher in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, weekday

I expected `toLocaleString` to return "Monday" (6 character),

but IE returned some unexpected character to me,

how can i get weekday correctly without another extension API (moment.js, etc..)

IE11:

```
var weekday = new Date('2015-11-23').toLocaleString("en-us", { weekday: 'long'});

weekday.toString() //"Monday"
weekday.length //7
weekday.charCodeAt(0) //8206 <-- what is this
```

Chrome53:

```
var weekday = new Date('2015-11-23').toLocaleString("en-us", { weekday: 'long'});

weekday.toString() //"Monday"
weekday.length //6
weekday.charCodeAt(0) //77
```

Comment: Why would you care? You're only using it for displaying dates, right?

Comment: Because i need to sort them, like ('Monday', 'Tuesday' ...) or ('Sunday', 'Monday' ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I did some investigating:

Character 8206 is a [Left-to-right mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm), most likely added in by MS as part of its internationalization rules.

It can be easily stripped out.

```
var stripped = weekday.replace(/\u200E/g, "");
console.log(stripped.length)
```

Just a note: You may also encounter character 8207, which is a right-to-left mark -- that can be stripped just as easily.